# Google Sheets sum of columns where cell value matches multiple columns in another sheet

Tags: filter, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula in Google Sheets which will lookup a cell across multiple columns in another sheet and return the sum of cells where that value is contained.

Here's my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z2XUqG1_3g0N__5Ab1R-8Dr8Bk-Z88x6nYvOdhYw78Q/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just filter it inside of `SUM` like:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Sheet2!C$2:C, (Sheet2!A$2:A=A2)+(Sheet2!B$2:B=A2)))
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

You can Add 3 columns red flag,green flag and blue flag.

then use IF function and but 1 if it belongs to the color.

```
=if( OR( A2="red",B2 ="red"),1,0)
```

[image]

then you  create a new 3 columns red count, green count and blue count
and multiply Quantity by the color flag.

```
=C2*H2
```

[image]

then use Sum function to add it in the other sheet

```
=sum(Sheet2!K2:Sheet2!K10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `sumproduct`:

```
=sumproduct(Sheet2!A:A=A2,Sheet2!C:C)+sumproduct(Sheet2!B:B=A2,Sheet2!C:C)-sumproduct(Sheet2!A:A=A2,Sheet2!B:B=A2,Sheet2!C:C)
```

The first two `sumproducts` add col C values if either col A or col B matches the colour.

The third `sumproduct` removed the double count where both col A and col B match the colour.